# Android Studio breakpoints in Kotlin code do not work (No executable code found)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging, breakpoints

I am working with Android Studio 4.1.2 on macOS to update an existing, Java based Android app. I have now added Kotlin support to the project for the first time. While the Kotline code can be used without any problem, breakpoints within the code do not work:

```
// Kotlin file Utils.kt
package com.example.myApp

fun doSomething(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
    Log.d("Debug", "I did something...")
    val sum = a + b
    return sum
}

// Some JAVA file
... 
int result = UtilsKt.doSomething(1, 2);
```

Using breakpoints anywhere in the JAVA code works fine. But when Setting a breakpoint to the `val sum = a + b` line (or anywhere else in the Kotlin code) a disabled gray circle is shown instead of the usual red dot and hovering with the mouse over it shows the hint

> No executable code found at line 42 in class com.example.myApp.UtilKt

[image]

Log output shows, that the code actually did run. Also, setting a breakpoint at the Java code that calls the Kotlin code works fine, and stepping into the Kotlin code from there is no problem either.

Cleaning the project, restarting Android Studio, etc. did not help. **Any idea how to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

try to click on [Apply code changes] if it didn't work try to [invalidate caches/restart]
its an issue in android studio IDE on version 4.1 and above[image]

Comment: Thanks. Using "Apply code changes" does not make any difference. Also, this would only make sense to apply changes to a running debug session, wouldn't it? However, the problem also shows up when recompiling / restarting the app. Using "invalidate cache/restart" had no effect either.

Comment: you can find  "invalidate cache/restart" in file menu 12th option

Answer (score 0):

try to use breakpoint also where you call method.

Comment: Stepping into the Kotlin code from a Java breakpoint is no problem. But this does not solve the problem, that I cannot set breakpoints in Kotlin itself.

Comment: if your code like that 
var result = UtilsKt.doSomething(1, 2) try to start using breakpoint from there. I think kotlin needs to know where to start watching points. If it still not solved, i actually dont know. Maybe restarting android studio can solve the problem